# Sonarqube docker image 8.2 failing in azure web app backed by azure sql

Tags: sonarqube, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-for-containers

**Hosted** : Azure Web Apps Container using sonarqube docker image 8.2 community
**Database** : Azure SQL

**Issue:**
When I try to configure the docker 8.2 community edition I am getting “didn’t respond to HTTP pings on port: 9000, failing site start”. 
However, when I use docker 7.1 image, everything works like a charm with the same database and environment configuration.

8.2 community docker image works with “Embedded database”. For this, to work I need to remove all settings mentioned below from web app’s appsettings but I cannot use Embedded database for production.

**Web App container Appsetting:**
SONARQUBE_JDBC_URL:
jdbc:sqlserver://xxx-sql.xxx.mock.net:1433;databaseName=sonar;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;
SONARQUBE_JDBC_USERNAME: username
SONARQUBE_JDBC_PASSWORD: password

**Logs:**
2020-04-18T07:22:00.087917276Z ERROR: [1] bootstrap checks failed
2020-04-18T07:22:00.088256776Z [1]: max virtual memory areas vm.max_map_count [65530] is too low, increase to at least [262144]

2020-04-18 07:21:06.713 INFO - Starting container for site
2020-04-18 07:21:06.714 INFO - docker run -d -p 1345:9000 --name sonarapp_0_338a176e -e WEBSITE_SITE_NAME=sonarapp -e WEBSITE_AUTH_ENABLED=False -e PORT=9000 -e WEBSITE_ROLE_INSTANCE_ID=0 -e WEBSITE_HOSTNAME=xxx.mywebsites.net -e WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID=c5ca023cf00c345rft6fder34sdeb31ebeba5d4ab2694580a387d9fd4508b6a79 sonarqube:8.2-community

2020-04-18 07:21:08.556 INFO - Initiating warmup request to container sonarapp_0_338a176e for site sonarapp
2020-04-18 07:21:25.891 INFO - Waiting for response to warmup request for container sonarapp_0_338a176e. Elapsed time = 17.3347129 sec
2020-04-18 07:22:01.392 ERROR - Container sonarapp_0_338a176e for site sonarapp has exited, failing site start
2020-04-18 07:22:01.414 ERROR - Container sonarapp_0_338a176e didn’t respond to HTTP pings on port: 9000, failing site start. See container logs for debugging.
2020-04-18 07:22:01.500 INFO - Stoping site sonarapp because it failed during startup.

Comment: How do you want to run it in the Azure Web App?

Comment: @CharlesXu I want to configure the SonarQube front end in web app container and the backend in Azue SQL. However, it is currently failing whilst starting the elasticserach bootstrap validation and eventually sonarqube container stops.

Error:
bootstrap checks failed  max virtual memory areas vm.max_map_count [65530] is too low, increase to at least [262144]

Comment: Can you share what do you set to associate it with the Azure SQL? I think you can provide details about the setting that you used when you create the Web app.